# Add a new filter clause

Tags: view, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to get a filter on a view which I think I can't get using AND/OR blocks with the currently available choices. Is it possible to add another choice which would be: "Show me the records whose due date is everything beginning from yesterday and earlier".

Or do I need a plugin to do that ? Closest thing I could think of is "Yesterday" and "Last 20 years" but that will show today's records too...

If a plugin is needed, I was thinking on enabling it on `RetrieveMultiple` for the `Activity` entity, but I would need to be able to catch the name of the view that was used so I can do my plugin's logic only if the user was browsing records using a specific view. Is this possible?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to see "today's records" too, then unfortunately this isn't possible with out-of-the-box filters.

However, I suggest a simple workflow: it would wait until the due date and then set a hidden checkbox field called something like "Overdue" to true. Then your filter will be very easy to build. You could also have this workflow send an email reminder to the owner of the record.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem with the workflow approach is that this workflow will need to be created for each activity type (can't create a workflow on "ActivityPointer :( ).
So I'd like to know if it's possible to intercept `RetrieveMultiple` messages in a plugin, determine the name of the view that was used to list `queueitems` and tweak the filters from the plugin ?

Comment: Perhaps! But I'm betting it is simpler to define a simple workflow on each activity type. :)